# How to create Laravel Fortify 2FA as a middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-fortify

I am new to Laravel and using version 8. I have installed Fortify and uses Laravel UI as the front-end login. I have enabled Fortify 2FA but it only requested upon login, how do I convert Fortify 2FA as a middleware to use it in other web routes? Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you!

Example to protect a web route using Foritfy 2FA in web.php
`Route::get('/example', [ExampleController, 'index'])->middleware('Fortify 2FA')->name('example.index');`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to enforce 2FA for some of your web routes, but not others?
I don't think fortify has middleware to do this so I created my own.

By creating a middleware class with the following contents:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Require2FA
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $request->user()->two_factor_confirmed_at) {
            return redirect('require-2fa');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Any users who have not enabled 2FA will be redirected to '/require-2fa'

This is assuming you are already protecting those routes with the auth middleware, to ensure they are logged in.

[Laravel's middleware documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/middleware#main-content) will walk you through it.